# How to use getParameterNames() value

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am getting parameters name and values from from UI to my servlet using `getParameterNames`. Now I want to use those values to run my query but I don't know how to do that I am getting errors while doing that

**What I am doing**

From Ui having Dynamic stars so getting values using `getParameterNames()`, then try to use that values.

If user selects 5 stars I am getting its parameter and its values as 1 because `excellent` is defined as 1 in my data base `very good` as 2 and so on to `poor` as 5.

So I am getting values as after click on save

```
Parameter Name is 'Quality Of Food' and Parameter Value is '3'
Parameter Name is 'Cleanliness' and Parameter Value is '3'
Parameter Name is 'Service' and Parameter Value is '3'
Parameter Name is 'Staf Behavior' and Parameter Value is '3'
Parameter Name is 'Ambience' and Parameter Value is '2'
```

Now I am running a query in my Java servlet doPost class to get respective attributes to values. For example, for value 2 attribute name is `excellent` like that.

After that I have to insert all this data into my db.

The main thing is all the stars are dynamic as coming from database as JSON so it can vary currently I am having 5 attributes of 5-5 stars to show on UI on click of submit getting data in back end

**My code**

```
Connection con = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    java.util.Date dateUtil = new Date();
    java.sql.Date dateSql = new java.sql.Date(dateUtil.getTime());
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(dateUtil.getTime());

    try {
        con = DBConnection.createConnection();
        statement = con.createStatement();
        Enumeration en = request.getParameterNames();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object objOri = en.nextElement();
            String param = (String) objOri;
            String value = request.getParameter(param);
             System.out.println("Parameter Name is '" + param + "' and Parameter Value is '" + value + "'");
            String getSql = "select ATTRIBUTENAME from FEEDBACKATTRUBUTES where POSITIONNO=" + value
                    + " and ATTRIBUTETYPE ='STARRING'";
            String updateSql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERFEEDBACK (CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMERNAME, BILLNO, BILLDATE, ATTRIBUTE1, ATTRIBUTE2, ATTRIBUTE3, ATTRIBUTE4, ATTRIBUTE5, ATTRIBUTE6, ATTRIBUTE7, ATTRIBUTE8, ATTRIBUTE9, ATTRIBUTE10, REMARKS, CREATEDTIMESTAMP, SMSSENT)"
                    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(getSql);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String attributeName = resultSet.getString("ATTRIBUTENAME");
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateSql);
                ps.setString(1, "123456");
                ps.setString(2, "Dheeraj");
                ps.setString(3,"-");
                ps.setDate(4,dateSql);
                ps.setString(5, param+":"+attributeName); //how can i insert these values
                ps.setString(6, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(7, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(8, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(9, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(10, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(11, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(12, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(13, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(14, param+":"+attributeName);
                ps.setString(15, "remark");
                ps.setTimestamp(16, timestamp);
                ps.setString(17, "N");

                ps.addBatch();
                ps.executeBatch();
            }

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL EXCPTION   91");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As in my code you can check from `ps.setString(5, param+":"+attributeName); //how can I insert these values` this line param and value (attribute name I am inserting) but I have got only 5 attributes values from UI for all others I have to insert `-`.

[image: This is how I have to save data in db]

My main issue is currently I am having only five attributes on my UI but here in Java class insert query I have to insert 5 and other as null or `-`.

For better understanding, [this is my UI](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/2bj3hukz/).

Comment: You're inserting the same value for all 10 "attribute<n>" columns. That can't be right.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thats what I want to know how can I insert all the distinct values, can you please help me out with some idea

Comment: switch the iteration cycles; or first load the names-values into local variables, and use them;

Comment: @JozefChocholacek can you help with some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the sequence of the process, first you need to store the params and their values locally and then add them to the prepared statement before executing it.
Here is a modified version of your code that does it:

```
Connection con = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    java.util.Date dateUtil = new Date();
    java.sql.Date dateSql = new java.sql.Date(dateUtil.getTime());
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(dateUtil.getTime());

    try {
        con = DBConnection.createConnection();
        statement = con.createStatement();
        Enumeration en = request.getParameterNames();
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>  evaluation = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer,String >  classifications = new HashMap<>();  
        String getSql = "select ATTRIBUTENAME,POSITIONNO from FEEDBACKATTRUBUTES where ATTRIBUTETYPE ='STARRING'";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(getSql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            classifications.put(resultSet.getInt("POSITIONNO"),resultSet.getString("ATTRIBUTENAME"));
        }

        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object objOri = en.nextElement();
            String param = (String) objOri;
            String value = request.getParameter(param);
            System.out.println("Parameter Name is '" + param + "' and Parameter Value is '" + value + "'");
            evaluation.put(param,Integer.parseInt(value));
         }  

            String updateSql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERFEEDBACK (CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMERNAME, BILLNO, BILLDATE, ATTRIBUTE1, ATTRIBUTE2, ATTRIBUTE3, ATTRIBUTE4, ATTRIBUTE5, ATTRIBUTE6, ATTRIBUTE7, ATTRIBUTE8, ATTRIBUTE9, ATTRIBUTE10, REMARKS, CREATEDTIMESTAMP, SMSSENT)"
                    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateSql);
            ps.setString(1, "123456");
            ps.setString(2, "Dheeraj");
            ps.setString(3,"-");
            ps.setDate(4,dateSql);
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> evaluationIterator = evaluation.entrySet().iterator();
            int i = 5;
            while (i<15) {
                if(evaluationIterator.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String, String> entry = evaluationIterator.next();
                ps.setString(i, entry.getKey()+":"+classifications.get(entry.getValue()));
                }
                else{
                    ps.setString(i, "");
                }
                i++;
            }
            ps.setString(15, "remark");
            ps.setTimestamp(16, timestamp);
            ps.setString(17, "N");

            ps.addBatch();
            ps.executeBatch();




    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL EXCPTION   91");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

please let me know if this works for you, note that the code is not tested and could contain errors.

Comment: hey these `ATTRIBUTE1` `ATTRIBUTE2` are dynamic whose codes are coming from ui as 1,2,3,4,5 then from db I am getting there respective name `excellent` for 1 `v good` for 2 and so on

Comment: I did not understand your question at the beginning, check the updated answer, and let me know if this works for you

Comment: let me check please

Comment: hey the value you used in `getSql` is not defined  `String getSql = "select ATTRIBUTENAME from FEEDBACKATTRUBUTES where POSITIONNO=" + value
                    + " and ATTRIBUTETYPE ='STARRING'";`  because value is inside while, and if I declare  that globally it is not taking the dynamic value please check

Comment: hey getting this ` At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized.` error as I thing I am getting only five attributes other five I have to insert as `-` or null please check my database Image

Comment: I edited the code so it gets the classifications then interprets the values , and after that, it tries to add the parameters and their classifications to the table.

Comment: hey `classifications.resultSet.getString("ATTRIBUTENAME");` this shows error as `resultSet cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: I think it would be like `classifications.add(resultSet.getString("ATTRIBUTENAME"));` this

Comment: same error I am getting `At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized.`

Comment: that's right, there was a simple error in the While loop that adds the attributes, I simply replaced the 5 with the i, check the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198295/discussion-between-manish-thakur-and-alaa-abuiteiwi).